# Adding data from multiple check boxes to cell

Tags: vba, excel

I've seen some similar posts to this one but I'm not 100% sure how to make it work for my existing UserForm.  What I have is 5 check boxes that if checked will enter data to the cell, including if multiple boxes are checked.  So if HU and OS are checked it will read something like HU,OS.

The form right now adds information to a new line and I would like for it to continue doing that. I've tried some of the other methods I've seen but they don't seem to work with my very basic coding here.   Below are screenshots of the form and the coding.

Coding:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim emptyRow As Long

'Make Sheet1 active
Sheet1.Activate

'Determine emptyRow
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

'Transfer information
Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = Position.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = Time.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = Callpriority.Value

If CellCB.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value & "Yes"

Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = Calltype.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = Transferto.Value

If HUCB.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = HUCB.Caption

If OSCB.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value & " " & OSCB.Caption

If CBCB.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value & " " & CBCB.Caption

If SCCB.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value & " " & SCCB.Caption

If TestCB.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value & " " & TestCB.Caption

Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = Code.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 9).Value = Phonenumber.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 10).Value = Comments.Value

ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Unload Me
Testlog.Show
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'Fill Position
With Position
    .AddItem "Police A"
    .AddItem "Police B"
    .AddItem "Fire A"
    .AddItem "Fire B"
    .AddItem "Trainer"
    .AddItem "Supervisor"
End With

'Empty Time
Time.Value = ""

'Fill Callpriority
With Callpriority
    .AddItem "Non-Emergency"
    .AddItem "Emergency"
    .AddItem "Unknown"
End With

'Fill Calltype
With Calltype
    .AddItem "Police"
    .AddItem "Fire"
    .AddItem "Medical"
End With

'Empty Transferto
Transferto.Value = ""

'Uncheck DataCheckBoxes
HUCB.Value = False
OSCB.Value = False
CBCB.Value = False
SCCB.Value = False
TestCB.Value = False
CellCB.Value = False

'Fill Code
With Code
    .AddItem "1"
    .AddItem "2"
    .AddItem "3"
    .AddItem "4"
    .AddItem "5"
    .AddItem "6"
    .AddItem "7"
    .AddItem "8"
    .AddItem "9"
    .AddItem "10"
End With

'Empty Phonenumber
Phonenumber.Value = ""

'Empty Comments
Comments.Value = ""

End Sub
```

[Log and Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvQvx.jpg)

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yy13i.jpg)

Comment: do web search for `vba how to concatenate strings`

Comment: Would that be the easiest way to accomplish this without having to re-write the entire thing? Isn't that more for adding information from one cell to another?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a String variable and add text to it as needed.

```
Dim sDisposition As String

' ... Your other codes ...

sDisposition = ""
If HUCB.Value = True Then
    If Len(sDisposition) > 0 Then sDisposition = sDisposition & " "
    sDisposition = sDisposition & HUCB.Caption
End If
If OSCB.Value = True Then
    If Len(sDisposition) > 0 Then sDisposition = sDisposition & " "
    sDisposition = sDisposition & OSCB.Caption
End If
If CBCB.Value = True Then
    If Len(sDisposition) > 0 Then sDisposition = sDisposition & " "
    sDisposition = sDisposition & CBCB.Caption
End If
If SCCB.Value = True Then
    If Len(sDisposition) > 0 Then sDisposition = sDisposition & " "
    sDisposition = sDisposition & SCCB.Caption
End If
If TestCB.Value = True Then
    If Len(sDisposition) > 0 Then sDisposition = sDisposition & " "
    sDisposition = sDisposition & TestCB.Caption
End If
Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = sDisposition ' typo here earlier...

' ... Your other codes ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This worked perfectly!  I'm still learning VBA so it's nice to be able to visualize how stuff works and doesn't work with what I've been working on.  Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome to VBA! I think the UserForm needs some rethink on design, sometimes Option buttons are better than ComboBox for short list. The bottom description should go next to some control? Change the label caption at the bottom at Initialize to have multiple lines `vbLf` or `vbCr` or `vbCrLf` - play with them!

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim sDisposition As String

Dim aaa As String
Dim bbb As String
Dim ccc As String
Dim ddd As String
Dim eee As String

aaa = ""
bbb = ""
ccc = ""
ddd = ""
eee = ""

If HUCB.Value Then aaa = HUCB.Caption        ' do not use   If true = true then ...
If OSCB.Value Then bbb = OSCB.Caption        ' just use     If true then ...
If CBCB.Value Then ccc = CBCB.Caption
If SCCB.Value Then ddd = SCCB.Caption
If TestCB.Value Then eee = TestCB.Caption

sDisposition = aaa & " " & bbb & " " & ccc & " " & ddd & " " & eee    ' concatenate string values

Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = sDisposition

' or do not use sDisposition and do this
Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = aaa & " " & bbb & " " & ccc & " " & ddd & " " & eee
```

Comment: Perhaps add `Trim()` before the last line as if none ticked, there will be 4 spaces in the cell.